# Is Excel's NORMSDIST function the Probability Density Function (PDF)?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand what is behind the `NORMSDIST` function and so far I have understood

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/advanced_excel_functions/advanced_excel_compatibility_normsdist_function

that it is the standard normal distribution where $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$ described by this Probability Density Function (PDF):

$$
\begin{equation} \label{eq:someequation}
f_X(x) = \frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-\frac 12 x^2} 
\end{equation}
$$
However when I am trying to compare for instance `NORMSDIST(1)` it gives me the value of `0.84134474606854300000` while my actual implementation of the equation $(1)$ give me a value of `0.241970725`. I would like to know if there is something wrong with the equation it self, is there any other implementation?

Comment: It’s the CDF, not the PDF. IIRC, there is an argument for the density, and this is in the excel documentation.

Comment: Here is the formula for the cumulative distribution function $=normdist(x,mean,standarddev,cumulative)=normdist(1,0,1,\color{red}1)$

The red $\color{red}1$ indicates that the cdf is calculated.

Comment: I am just trying to find the right formula/equation behind the `normsdist(x)` or `normdist(x,mean,standarddev,cumulative)` because I am trying to do my own implementation.